# What does "evaluate" mean in the Chrome profiler?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, profiling

What does `evaluate` mean in the function column when viewing a CPU profile in the Chrome debugger tools?

This line doesn't have a JS file associated with it, and has the single largest percentage in my total column – so I'd love to understand what this line means.

Comment: Could it mean calls to the JavaScript `eval()` function?